# SpinnerPreference? (How to embed a Spinner in a Preferences screen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, preferencescreen

Planting a Spinner in a [layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/) is straightforward, since there are so many samples and tutorials showing how to do just this.

But how to I plant a Spinner in a [PreferenceScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html)?

Is this possible/doable at all?

Note: I have already conducted an extensive search. There is no such thing as a "SpinnerPreference". I wish there were.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom `Preference` by extending the `Preference` class or `DialogPreference` class.
There is an example in the [Settings guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom) on developer.android.com.

Alternately you might want to consider using a `ListPreference`. The user gets to pick one value from a list of values. The UI is similar to the images in the tutorial you linked to.